# Headings and content in separate columns

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup, html-heading

I have a design where title goes on the left, and paragraphs go on the right like below.

[image]

I can easily accomplish this with Bootstrap columns, but would this be semantically correct? (i.e. having heading vs related content in different divs)? Would it be bad for WCAG 2.0 standards? From what I have read on w3.org, information on this is a bit dubious.

Example HTML:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"><h2>Section 1 Title</h2></div>
    <div class="col">
        <p>Seciton 1 paragraph 1</p>
        <p>Seciton 1 paragraph 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"><h2>Section 2 Title</h2></div>
    <div class="col">
        <p>Seciton 2 paragraph 1</p>
        <p>Seciton 2 paragraph 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post the HTML and CSS? A quick answer is no. Unless your doing something crazy like still using tables to format your layouts its most likely not an issue. My assumption is the heading and corresponding paragraph are in a container and floated using CSS? If so then that would pass WCAG 2.0 standards. But without your code I cant give you a definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is having each heading+paragraph appearing in order in the DOM (so heading 1, then corresponding paragraph, then heading 2, then corresponding paragraph, etc.).

But having superfluous `div` in between them to help on the layout is no problem. So what you did is totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @abourne, we need more code.  A screen reader user can navigate to a heading using either the "H" key or "1", "2", "3", etc for H1, H2, H3, respectively.  Once they do that, if they press the down arrow, they'll go to the next item in the accessibility tree (which often mirrors the DOM).  If the next item is not the paragraph text but rather the next heading, then yes this would be an accessibility problem.

But it depends how you implemented it.

Comment: Perfect.  The code you have is good.  The DOM order is what's important to screen readers.  If you move things around with CSS, the screen reader doesn't care.